# Oracle SQL - Select two substrings from one string and combine them in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, toad

Using Oracle Toad SQL.

I have one column in my test_table that has data in this kind of format:

```
column_1
abc-def-ghijklmn
```

I need to select exactly `abcdef` (without the '-' between them) from the row shown above. I tried it with two substrings:

```
SELECT (SUBSTR(column_1, 0, 3), SUBSTR(column_1, 5,3)) FROM test_table
```

but it does not work (the error was *"missing right parenthesis"*). **How do I select two separate substrings from a row and combine them in a new column?**

Answer (score 1):

Or (lines 1 and 2 are just sample data; you'd use line 3 for what you do. It fetches the 1st and 2nd *word* from the input string and concatenates them):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc-def-ghijklmn' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) || regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
------
abcdef

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to **concatenate** the two selected substrings:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(column_1, 0, 3), SUBSTR(column_1, 5,3)) FROM test_table
```

And in case you would need to concatenate more than two selected substrings, you have to use the concatenation operator, ||. Example:

```
SELECT (SUBSTR(column_1, 0, 3) || SUBSTR(column_1, 5,3) || SUBSTR(column_1, 5,2)) FROM test_table
```